# Scroll effect || Scroll div with browser window scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, effect

I have a question, how to make effect with scroll, where you scroll, but you scrolling only one part of page, for example look here : https://www.apple.com/lae/apple-music/

-- Scrolling in iPhone

Comment: Take a look here and see if this fits your needs. https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

Comment: Nope, I think that I must use Ajax, because when you scrolling iPhone is at one position, but content on screen changes

Comment: No, the page is scrolling for sure. Just open the dev console, enable emulation and look at the source. This isn't magic and it most certainly isn't doing an AJAX post every time you scroll. They are just using some css transitions/animations and a custom built framework make you think its not just standard scrolling. Just like fullPage.js.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to use a library like http://scrollmagic.io/
Here's the documentation: http://scrollmagic.io/docs/index.html